# heroku push failure with developments paths / dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails application with a Gemfile that contains the snippet below:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/linecache19-0.5.13/"
end
```

This never gave me a problem before today, when deploying to heroku.  For some reason when deploying I would get the following error:

```
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.0
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       The path `/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26` does not exist.
```

It seems that it was trying to access the path specified for that gem.  I don't think it should be doing that because that gem is in the development, test groups.  I have other gems in development, test that Heroku ignores correctly.

I got around this issue by temporarily commenting out this line from my Gemfile before pushing to Heroku.  This is annoying though and I am wondering if anyone knows why this problem occurred?  I have not had this issue until attempting to deply today.

Any explanations or suggestions would be appreciated.